# Make Eclipse's Java editor font the same as IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, editor

I just moved to Eclipse and can't get used to the new font style.
I'd like it to look exactly like IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 12. How do I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window->Preferences, and select General->Appearance. You can change the font in there. I don't know what IntelliJ uses, but you can probably look it up in IntelliJ, and just match it.

Comment: Apparently Idea uses the default "Monospaced" font for the JVM it's running on, which happens to be Courier New, which is the same as the eclipse font, however I had to set it to size 7 to get the same font as size 12 in Idea. Thanks

Comment: The link to download Monospaced is https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

Answer (score 5):

I have created a [Complete guide](https://techfact555.blogspot.com/2020/04/change-eclipsespring-tool-suite-sts-ide.html) to make Eclipse looks like IntelliJ Idea which comprises of UI, fonts, coloring and pretty much everything.